# ASP.NET MVC ntier architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, n-tier-architecture

I have a standard nteir setup :-

Web server -> App server -> DB server

I have an MVC 5 web application sitting on the web server with controllers calling a WCF services project sitting on the App server. WCF services project uses EF6 to marshal data on the DB server.

I am wondering if WCF is overkill? Is there is an easier way to achieve this same architecture? I am thinking I should have gone with Web API on the app server and then just call the web API from the controllers with the HTTPClient?

Or, I could even just use a plain MVC project on the App server returning JSONResults to the MVC controller on the web server?

Answer (score 0):

It depends...

You have to understand what are the benefits of each set up. This is not exhaustive, just a quick brain dump. This should give you some hints to look further as in the wild world there might be many more reasons for choosing one or another solution.

- Why WCF. Are you going to have different clients to your backend ? You need some entreprisy security between clients and you backend ? With WCF you could configure Http, TCP endpoints, set message or transport security and a lot more. It could be needed for example if your doing an intranet application and you would like not only to have your UI (MVC application) but other systems going to it. If this is not needed WCF seems overkill here.
- Web Api is also agreat choice if you would like to built more REST oriented api, enabling content-negotiation for different clients (different media-types). Building REST is not about issuing JSON, it's much more and this would be too long to explain it here. If your client is not only your MVC app, but you could have a need for a api for other mobile devices, OAuth authentication and the so, this could be a good way to do.
- Plain MVC app would also fit if you don't have any special needs, go for it. No overhead needed. **Keep It Simple And Stupid**.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I would not change this.

WCF is a good choice for communication between Web Tier and App Tier. I would never put my App Tier exposed to outside world, so if there is any communication to my app from outside world, it would be through Web tier only and if there is a need to support multiple clients, I would create a WebAPI on web tier and expose that.

I would keep App tier only available to Organization internal and with WCF I would have flexibility to write service code and contracts which can then be exposed over various bindings (transport, security, etc.).If you are building a service in your organization and plan to support multiple protocols, or simply use protocols other than HTTP (tcp, name pipes, udp, etc.) then WCF is indeed a good choice.